# Meaning of "It is also a mile high up in the sky."

Tags: sentence

Given the example:

> Denver is the capital of Colorado. It is also **a mile high up in the sky**. It is called the “Mile High City.”

Comment: It's a mile above sea level.

Comment: Normally, 'a mile high up in the sky' means a mile above the ground, but here it's used in a sensationalist way in the way KillingTime says. It's so far from the ocean that I didn't notice, but I suppose there's less available oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

Usually saying that something is a mile high would imply that it's in the air a mile above ground level (e.g. the infamous "mile high club"). However, Denver is 5,280 feet above sea level – exactly one mile (source: https://www.denver.org/articles/post/10-things-to-know-about-the-mile-high-city/ ). Thank you for the question, I've learnt something (always a good thing!).